# Using 'and' before the last value in get_the_term_list in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a way to use the word 'and' in the output of get_the_term_list?

```
<?php echo strip_tags(get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'stijl', ' ',', ')); ?>
```

This code results in this output:

> Onverwachte wending, Pakkend, Slasher, Slim, Spanning

But i want it to be:

> Onverwachte wending, Pakkend, Slasher, Slim and Spanning

So basically i want the last comma to turn into 'and'. Got no clue how to accomplish this. Is it even possible?

Comment: IDK but could you try using " instead of '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WordPress, `get_the_term_list` returns a formatted version of `get_the_terms`,
which returns an array of the terms on the post. We can use this to customize the format of the list.

Typically when I do this I add something like the following to functions.php:

```
// In functions.php
function so_63957175_niceTermList($taxonomy = 'category') {
    global $post;
    $term_list = '';
    $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, $taxonomy);
    $n = 1;
    if ($terms) {
        foreach($terms as $term) {
            if ($n < count($terms)) {
                $term_list .= $term->name . ', ';
            } else {
                $term_list = rtrim($term_list, ', ') .  ' and ' . $term->name;
            }
            ++$n;
        }
    }

    $term_list = rtrim($term_list, ', ');

    return $term_list;
}

// In your template file

<?php echo so_63957175_niceTermList('category'); ?>
```

Comment: Hi Dave, that function goes beyond my code writing knowledge. Do you mean i should change my code and use get_the_terms instead? BTW i added your function and it resulted in a critical error.

Comment: Hi @njinok, I have tested and updated the function above, it should be working properly now. I have also added some clarity for use. Add the top code to functions.php. Add the `<?php echo so_63957175_niceTermList('category'); ?>` to your template file.

Comment: Hi Dave, thanx you so much man, for helping me out with this! It works great and is exactly what i needed. I'm trying to understand what you did here but it goes way beyond my code writing capabilities. Very grateful you took the time to help me out. Awesome.

Comment: Happy to help. I'll try and explain a little bit: Adding this as a function allows you to use the code anywhere in your templates. We start with the WordPress global `$post` variable to access the post being displayed in the template. Then, we make a blank variable in `$term_list` and get the `$terms` for the post as an array. We loop over each term and add it to the blank list. We also do a check on the loop increment (`$n`) to see if it is the last loop,  adding "and" if it is. The `rtrim()` functions remove extra commas. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanx for explaining it. Makes a little more sense now. Take care and thanx again!